# Database error in code. What isn't working is the grade query

Tags: php

```
$Prereq = "SELECT PreReqId FROM PreReq WHERE CourseId ='$CCourseId'";
$Query1= mysqli_query($db,$Prereq);
$array1 = mysqli_fetch_array($query1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$value= $array1['PreReqId'];

foreach($value as $i => $test)
{
    $Grade = "SELECT Grade FROM Enrolled WHERE CourseId = '$test' AND UserId ='$UserId'";
    $query2= mysqli_query($db,$Grade);
    $array2= mysqli_fetch_array($query2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $value2= $array2['Grade'];

    if($value2 == 'A' || $value2 == 'B' || $value2 == 'C')
    { 
        return result = 1;

    }
    else
    {
        return result =0;
    }
}
```

I have to check for preqrequitie grades for courses before a user can enroll in a class. As is I am able to get and echo the right `prereqId`. What isn't working is the grade query. Not sure why.

Comment: When you say it "isn't working", what does that mean? Do you get an error (e.g. something like `mysqli_fetch_array() expects a mysqli_result, boolean given`)? Does the query not return any results? Is `$value2` not the grade you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Though the question is rather unclear. I can suggest the following;

- Your first query `$Prereq` only selects one value: `PreReqId`
- You
  have a typo in `$Query1`and than using it as `mysqli_fetch_array($query1,MYSQLI_ASSOC)`
- It is not clear where `$UserId` is being set.
- Try using [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent Sql injections

Try the following:

```
$Prereq = "SELECT * FROM PreReq WHERE CourseId ='$CCourseId'";
$query1= mysqli_query($db, $Prereq);

// loop through query results
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    // For each row perform another query
    $Grade = "SELECT Grade FROM Enrolled WHERE CourseId = '".$row['PreReqId ']."' AND UserId ='$userId'";
    $query2= mysqli_query($db, $Grade);
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        if($row2['Grade'] == 'A' || $row2['Grade']== 'B' || $row2['Grade'] == 'C')
        { 
            return result = 1;

        }
        else
        {
            return result =0;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your database perform this logic and just check if any prerequisites are missing?

```
function isStudentAllowedToEnroll($UserId, $CCourseId) {
    $student_may_enroll = false;

    // I assumed your MySQL connection is in the global scope, if not you can
    // also just pass it in as another argument to the function if you'd like
    global $db;

    // Find all prerequisites for the course, exclude the ones the student
    // has passed, then count how many are left
    $query = "
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   PreReq
          LEFT JOIN Enrolled
          ON        Enrolled.CourseId = PreReq.PreReqId
          AND       Enrolled.UserId = ?
          AND       Enrolled.Grade IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
        WHERE  PreReq.CourseId = ?
        AND    Enrolled.CourseId IS NULL
    ";

    if ($stmt = $db->prepare($query)) {
        // I'm assuming your ids are integers, if they're strings change "ii" to "ss"
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $UserId, $CCourseId);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->bind_result($missing_prerequisites);
            $stmt->fetch();

            if ($missing_prerequisites == 0) {
                // No missing prerequisites, student is allowed to enroll
                $student_may_enroll = true;
            }
        } else {
            trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_WARNING);
        }

        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        trigger_error($db->error, E_USER_WARNING);
    }

    return $student_may_enroll;
}
```

I can understand if the query is a bit confusing. What it does is find all prerequisites for the course from the `PreReq` table. For each prerequisite, it tries to find a matching course in the `Enrolled` table for the given student with a **passing** grade. It then discards those matches, so in the end it counts the number of prerequisites that the student has **not** passed; either because the student hasn't enrolled in it or because they don't have a passing grade for it.

Answer (score -1):

If the user id is an int value you should remove the single quotes.